# Array with hindi font data to be converted to json in php

Tags: php, json

I have hindi font data stores in my database using utf8_bin.
I am able to get it from the database and display it as it is using:

But, i want the output to be in json format showing the hindi font data clearly.
I tried using json_encode but it returns the data something like:

{"title":"\u0938\u0942\u0930\u094d\u092f\u094b\u0926\u092f","details":"\u0938\u0941\u092c\u0939\u094d \u0915\u093e \u0938\u092e\u092f\u094d"}1
{"title":"\u0905\u0928\u094d\u0917\u094d\u0930\u0947\u095b\u0940 \u0938\u0947 \u0939\u093f\u0928\u094d\u0926\u0940","details":"\u092a\u0930\u093f\u0935\u0930\u094d\u0924\u0928\u094d"}2
{"title":"\u0932\u094b\u0915\u094d \u0938\u092d\u093e","details":"\u092e\u094b\u092c\u0948\u0932\u0947 \u092a\u0930\u094d \u0907\u0938\u094d\u0924\u0947\u092e\u093e\u0932\u094d \u0939\u0947\u0924\u0941"}

Rather i want it to be like

{"title":सूर्योदय,"details":सुबह् का समय्}

Please suggest

Comment: That's a perfectly valid JSON represenation of Hindi. I see no problem with it. Why do you?

Comment: I expect the output to be like {"title":सूर्योदय,"details":सुबह् का समय्}

Answer (score 3):

This is default behaviour I think. But there are two things you could try

1. If you're using PHP 5.4 you could set the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE option flag.
2. If you're using another version, try the following workaround:

   ```
   array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key) {
       if(is_string($item)) {
           $item = htmlentities($item);
       }
   });
   $json = json_encode($array);
   $rson = html_entity_decode($rson);
   ```

Comment: 1 I'd agree to, but why 2? There's no need for it.

Comment: Because if he's using an older version, there won't be a JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE flag and we'll have to manage another way. 2 does just that. Convert the characters before converting it to a json-string and convert them back after that.

Comment: Yes, sure, but the entire premise is questionable, since it's already valid JSON as-is with escaped Unicode code points. As such the workaround seems overly complicated to solve a non-issue.

Comment: I'm just telling him a way on how to do what he wants. I'm not questioning his objective (maybe he wants easier debugging or whatever)

Comment: Let me brief you the context. I have to create a webservice returning data in json format. The data in this case contains Hindi font and is required in the same way at receiving end. I understood the point that \u0989.... and so i a valid json representation, but i just want the format to be json and not the data converted.

Comment: i want the conversion of this array to json:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => अन्ग्रेज़ी से हिन्दी [details] => परिवर्तन् ) [1] => Array ( [title] => लोक् सभा [details] => मोबैले पर् इस्तेमाल् हेतु ) )

Comment: @Priya Yes, we understand. I'm still questioning *why* you want that, but whatever... @Louis' solution works, so +1. I'd recommend that if you can simply use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag and prefer to do so, do it. Otherwise there should be no actual *need* for this other than preference, so I wouldn't worry too much about it. If really necessary, the workaround is ugly but valid.